# How can I load Flutter text assets from a build context without reloading each build?

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm confused about the Flutter documentation on [loading text assets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-text-assets).

It states:

> Each Flutter app has a `rootBundle` object for easy access to the main asset bundle. It is possible to load assets directly using the `rootBundle` global static from `package:flutter/services.dart`.
>
> However, it’s recommended to obtain the `AssetBundle` for the current `BuildContext` using `DefaultAssetBundle`, rather than the default asset bundle that was built with the app; this approach enables a parent widget to substitute a different `AssetBundle` at run time, which can be useful for localization or testing scenarios.

I don't understand how I can implement text asset loading the recommended way, while at the same time avoiding to load the assets each time the widget is built.

Consider the following naive example that uses a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to display some text:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var greeting = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/greeting');
  return FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: greeting,
    builder (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text(snapshot.requireData);
      } else {
        return Text('Loading greeting...');
      }
    }
  );
}
```

In the example, [`loadString`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle/loadString.html) is called whenever the widget is built. This seems inefficient to me.

Also, it goes explicitly against the `FutureBuilder` documentation, which tells me that:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Now, I could go ahead and load my assets in any of the recommended methods, but none of them has a `BuildContext`. Meaning I'd have to use the `rootBundle`, which wasn't recommended.

Since I'm new to Flutter, I'm unsure if the documentation is contradicting itself or if there's some obvious thing I'm missing here. Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution for loading assets the way it's recommended in the Flutter docs.

Load the assets in a Widget's State and assign the Future to a nullable instance variable. This works in conjunction with FutureBuilder. Here's an example:

```dart
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  Future<String>? _greeting;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Wrapping `loadString` in a condition such as the following ensures that
    // the asset is loaded no more than once. Seems kinda crude, though.
    if (_greeting == null) {
      _greeting = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/greeting');
    }

    return FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: greeting,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.requireData);
          } else {
            return Text('Loading greeting...');
          }
        });
  }
}
```

This approach ensures that both recommendations from the Flutter docs are honored:

- Assets are loaded from the `Bundle` for the current `BuildContext`.
- Assets are loaded only once, avoiding that `FutureBuilder` restarts each build.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Save my time. Could you please share with me link from docs where you find such information.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to you... Remove Future builder.
You can do something like this:

```
  String greeting;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      greeting =
          await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/greeting');
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (greeting != null && greeting.isNotEmpty) {
      return Text(greeting);
    } else {
      return Text('Loading greeting...');
    }
  }
```

Comment: While I appreciate your answer, I get the feeling that it won't work, for the same reason as @eishon's answer. You're grabbing the `DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)` in a scope where `context` is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String greeting;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => loadString());
}

void loadString() async {
    if (greeting != null && greeting.isNotEmpty) {
        greeting = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/greeting');
        setState(() {});
    }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(greeting ?? 'Loading greeting...');
}
```

If your project has Null Safety then change `String greeting` to `String? greeting`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, though I don't think this is going to work. You're trying to access `DefaultAssetsBundle.of(context)`, but `context` is not defined inside `loadString()`. The `BuildContext` is only available in the `build` method (and methods called by it).