# Flutter web application stucks on`rootBundle.loadString`

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

While app is loading I'm trying to load some json:

```dart
final contentJson = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/content.json');
```

But app loading stucks and white screen is displaying. No errors appear in the console.

Here my `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
flutter:
  generate: true
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/content.json
```

I have a guess that this is related to the web application. Because this doesn't happen on other platforms.

Here full code surrounding invocation:

`home_data_provider.dart`

```dart
@override
  Future<List<ArticleDto>> getArticleDtos() async {
    final contentJson = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/content.json');
    final content = json.decode(contentJson) as Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>;

    return List<ArticleDto>.from(
      content.map((articleData) async {
        final articlePath = articleData['articlePath'] as String;
        final article = await rootBundle.loadString(articlePath);

        return ArticleDto(
          title: articleData['title'] as String,
          topic: articleData['topic'] as String,
          articleInMarkdown: article,
          imagePath: articleData['imagePath'] as String,
          createdAt: articleData['createdAt'] as String,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

`home_repository.dart`

```dart
@override
  Future<List<ArticleEntity>> getArticles() async {
    final articleDtos = await _dataProvider.getArticleDtos();
    return _articlesConverter.convertMultiple(articleDtos).toList();
  }
```

`home_page.dart`

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: createHomeCubit,
        child: SomeChild()),
    );
```

`create_home_cubit.dart`

```dart
HomeCubit createHomeCubit(BuildContext context) {
  final localeService = context.read<ILocaleService>();
  return HomeCubit(
    context.read<IThemeService>(),
    context.read<ILocaleService>(),
    HomeRepository(
      articlesConverter: ArticlesConverter(),
      dataProvider: HomeDataProvider(localeService.currentLocale.languageCode),
    ),
  );
}
```

`getArticles` will be called inside cubit constructor.

Comment: Try to load json file in initState of your page. Or you can do it with FutureBuilder.

Comment: add the full code surrounding the invocation of rootBundle.loadString()

Comment: @EgorGrischenkov put for Json fetching code in try-catch and watch for the error in the catch block.

Comment: @TusharPatel, sorry my fault but I have try/catch inside the cubit. And nothing happens there. It seems like something can't evaluates inside `rootBundle.loadString`.

Comment: does app work if you don't load this file ? White screen can be caused by other issues as well so try to isolate any other issue.

Comment: @ClevinoAlrin, Yeah if I'm removing routeBundle.loadString all works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the expected answer:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> loadJsonData() async {
// Load the JSON file using rootBundle
String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/content.json');

// Parse the JSON string
Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(jsonString);

return jsonData;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what exactly you answered? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68791006/15174002)

I'm starting to think that the problem is due to the fact that the method `rootBundle.loadString` call occurs during the execution of the `build` method.
I don't fully understand why this is a problem, but it helped.